# Need to put the output of below selenium code to a Json file

Tags: json, python-2.7, selenium-chromedriver

## need to parse the output data and dump it into a json file. Any help will be appreciated.

```
executable_path = "/usr/local/share/chromedriver"
chrome_options = Options()
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, 
chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://environment.netronline.com/api/viewers//env-
app.php?addr=gilbert")
time.sleep(5)
listOfElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='pinBox']//div[@class='pin']")
for element in listOfElements:
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
    hover.perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    targetTooltip = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='tooltip']")
    print targetTooltip.text
    print "**********************"
```

output is :
Emergency Response Notification System (ERNS)
Left click the pin for more info.

Incident: CALLER STATED THAT A WEST BOUND FREIGHT TRAIN STRUCK A TRESPASSER ON THE TRACKS.
Incident Date: 7/3/2012 6:20
Incident location: MP: 926.96
Year Reported: 2012
City: GILBERT
State: AZ
County: MARICOPA

---

US RCRA Generators (CESQG, SQG, LQG)
Left click the pin for more info.

Info URL: http://ofmpub.epa.gov/enviro/fii_query_detail.disp_program_facility?p_registry_id=110045500757
EPA Identifier: 110045500757
Primary Name: CVS PHARMACY #3268
Address: 765 S LINDSAY RD
City: GILBERT
County: MARICOPA
State: AZ
Zipcode: 85296-3063
Programs: AZURITE, BR, RCRAINFO
Program Interests: HAZARDOUS WASTE BIENNIAL REPORTER, LQG, STATE MASTER
Updated On: 27-JAN-2015 13:51:45
Recorded On: 10-MAY-2012 16:46:54

---

Required json format is :
[
      {
         "source":"Emergency Response Notification System (ERNS)",
     "Incident":"CALLER STATED THAT A WEST BOUND FREIGHT TRAIN STRUCK A TRESPASSER ON THE TRACKS.",
         "Incident Date":"7/3/2012 6:20",
         "Incident location":"MP: 926.96",
         "Year Reported":"2012",
         "City":"GILBERT",
         "State":"AZ",
         "County":"MARICOPA"
      }
]

Comment: Need go get the json output like this,
[
      {
         "source":"Emergency Response Notification System (ERNS)",
  "Incident":"CALLER STATED THAT A WEST BOUND FREIGHT TRAIN STRUCK A TRESPASSER ON THE TRACKS.",
        "Incident Date":"7/3/2012 6:20",
        "Incident location":"MP: 926.96",
       "Year Reported":"2012",
       "City":"GILBERT",
         "State":"AZ",
         "County":"MARICOPA"
      }
]

Comment: Need a help in parsing the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran the code in python 3.5 so changed urllib2 to urllib3.
Next change is passing chrome driver path in method webdriver.chrome().
You can download chrome diver from "https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/".

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import urllib3
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\raj.damani\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://environment.netronline.com/api/viewers//env-app.php?addr=gilbert#")
time.sleep(8)
listOfElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="pinBox"]//div[@class="pin"]')
for element in listOfElements:
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
    hover.perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    targetTooltip = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tooltip"]')
    print(targetTooltip.text)
    print("**********************")
```

Comment: I am getting the data, its like this :
Emergency Response Notification System (ERNS)
Left click the pin for more info.

Incident: CALLER STATED THAT A WEST BOUND FREIGHT TRAIN STRUCK A TRESPASSER ON THE TRACKS.
Incident Date: 7/3/2012 6:20
Incident location: MP: 926.96
Year Reported: 2012
City: GILBERT
State: AZ
County: MARICOPA
**********************

Comment: I am stuck up in parsing the data.

Comment: You can approach either of the two things for parsing, re module or json module. 
I guess re module is better for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

## I found the logic

```
driver.get("http://environment.netronline.com/api/viewers//env-app.php?addr=gilbert")
time.sleep(5)
listOfElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='pinBox']//div[@class='pin']")
for element in listOfElements:
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
    hover.perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    targetTooltip = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='tooltip']")
    for li in targetTooltip:
        lines = str(li.text)
        lines = str(lines).split('\n')
        lines.remove('Left click the pin for more info.')
        lines.remove('')
        lines.insert(0,'Environmental Concern')
        lines = [i.split(':', 1) for i in lines]
        flat_list = flatten(lines)
    r = dict(zip(flat_list[::2], flat_list[1::2]))
print json.dumps(r)
```